# Sending input to a screen session from outside

Tags: gnu-screen

My scenario is this:

I have a screen session running in a remote location. Inside this screen is a consoled-based program. When run without screen, this program starts in the terminal and accepts commands on its standard input.

What I want is a way to remotely send a command to screen so that this command is received by the console program. Maybe like this:

My PC -> SSH Send Msg Auto -> Screen Session -> Program (Run command received)

So from a remote PC I can send via SSH commands to the screen which sends them to the program. The program accepts them and executes them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to send input to a program running inside a screen session. You can do this with screen's `stuff` command. Use screen's `-X` option to execute a command in a screen session without attaching to it.

```
screen -S sessionname -p windowname -X stuff 'command1
command2
'
```

If you want to see the program's output, see the `hardcopy`, `log` and `logfile` commands.

Comment: Already tried the stuff command but it only sends commands that are from screen. You see it accepts only the commands that are screen related, not the program am using related.

Comment: @CYREX: `stuff` sends characters, exactly as if you had typed them. What exactly did you try, what was the intended effect, and what happened instead?

Comment: I see you have the -p part. I did not have that. Added that part and it is sending the command now but how can i press ENTER for each command?

Comment: Found it. Addint $ before the quotes and having C like escapes in it. Like this -X stuff $'show users\n'

Comment: @CYREX: `-p` is necessary (or at least a good idea) if there is more than one window. To “press Enter”, just include a newline in the argument (i.e. inside the quotes), as I've done.

Comment: `-p` is also necessary if you have just created a session without attaching to it, because no window is selected by default.

Comment: @ChrisDown Indeed, see [sending text input to a detached screen](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13953/13961#13961)

Answer (score 1):

**To send a command to a detached screen:**

```bsh
screen -S <screen_name> -X stuff "command blah blah blah\n"
```

- Be sure to have "\n" at the end of the command.  If you don't append the "\n", then the command will be sent but won't initiate.

*Side Note* :  If you want to leave a `screen` that you are inside of without ending it, use the following key-bind shortcut to detach from it: `ctrl + a + d` (`C-a-d`)

Comment: Hello, thanks for a contribution - looks good. Is that `SCREEN` following the `-S` a screen name (`<screen name>`)? Also what is the "stuff" parameter?

Comment: @DannyStaple

[stuff](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) *string*

Stuff the string string in the input buffer of the current window. This is like the "paste" command but with much less overhead. You cannot paste large buffers with the "stuff" command. It is most useful for key bindings. See also "bindkey".