# Unable to 'stuff' commands into a created 'screen' immediately after creating it

Tags: gnu-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sending text input to a detached screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13953/sending-text-input-to-a-detached-screen)

With reference to the answered question: 
[Sending input to a screen session from outside](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5305/sending-input-to-a-screen-session-from-outside)

I am trying to write a script that will create a `screen` and then `stuff` input (in my case, UNIX commands) into the shell that I want it to execute.

Here's what I have till now:

```
$ screen -dmS new_screen bash

$ screen -S new_screen -X stuff "cd /some/path/
some_script_file.sh
" <--This new line is required to execute the above command. 
$ # Note: See comments. We could insert the newline character instead of 'hard-coding' a newline string literal.
```

For some reason, the screen gets created fine and enters the `bash` shell. But the `cd` and `some_script_file.sh` commands don't get stuffed to the screen's bash shell.

Now the really strange part is.. After I detach from the screen, re-execute the stuff command as below..

```
$ screen -S new_screen -X stuff "cd /some/path/
some_script_file.sh
"
```

and then attach back into new_screen. Now I see that the commands were correctly stuffed and executed in the bash shell inside screen.

Not sure where I am going wrong here, there seems to be any issue stuff-ing commands into a not as yet attached screen.

Comment: In *tmux* you have to provide the `ENTER` word to signify you are done.  Pretty sure you need to do the same with screen.

Comment: @vgoff I guess that is handled when we add the newline character placing the double quotes on the new line. I guess an alternative way would be to write $ screen -S new_screen -X stuff "cd /some/path/^M
some_script_file.sh^M"

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you...

Comment: @vgoff Yup it worked. I replaced the newline literals with the UNIX newline character (represented as ^M). This is done by opening the script in vi, then in insert mode I presses [CTRL] + [V] followed by [ENTER] to insert ^M (return key).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a screen session is first created, no window is selected. As such, when you send your commands, screen doesn't know which window to send it to. Once you have attached to the screen, however, the window has become selected, which is why you can send commands after doing so. To select a window from the command line you need to use the `-p` option.

Here's a modification of your command that should work:

```bash
screen -S new_screen -p 0 -X stuff "cd /some/path/
some_script_file.sh
"
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris! Yes that seemed to be the issue. I just came across a similar issue discussed here [sending-text-input-to-a-detached-screen](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13953/sending-text-input-to-a-detached-screen/13954#13954); but you have summarized it well.

Comment: So a return literal inside the string.  Would this work with pipes?  Would you still need the return as the last character?

Comment: @vgoff I added a post below to answer your questions..

Comment: I literally watched you post them... the comment and the edit.

Comment: Haha Okay. Well I am new to scripting and just wanted this post to be as informative as possible..

Answer (score 0):

***@vgoff***: *"So a return literal inside the string. Would this work with pipes? Would you still need the return as the last character? – vgoff"*

Looking at using a return literal or a return character (^M):

```
bash-3.00$ echo "(1) This sentence
> (2) has
> (3) 3 returns
> (4) in it.
> " | grep "has";
(2) has
```

Well looks like a return literal does not affect pipping. And we need a return before the closing quote to act as a RETURN key to send the echo statement for execution.

Comment: My comment was in regards to stuffing to screen.  You don't do that here, and so the experiment, though a fine experiment, doesn't answer the question in regards to 'stuffing screen'.  You can edit this answer though, so that is good.