# Screen in bash script

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I am using a bash script and I need to create a screen, execute a specific command with a memory limit and detach the screen.

I have been trying something similar:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
do
    test="test"$i
    screen -dmS test
    screen -r test -X ulimit -v 2199552
    screen -r test -X ./my_command $i
done
```

...but it doesn't work. In particular, the screen is created, but ./my_command is not executed. Any hint?

Answer (score 6):

First, you want `$test` rather than `test` on the `screen` lines in your script.

The -X command is expecting *screen* commands, not *shell* commands.  You could look through the man page and figure out how to tell screen to type in the characters into the running shell; it's probably possible but I couldn't find it in a couple minutes.  (aha, it's the screen "stuff" command:  [Sending input to a screen session from outside](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5305/sending-input-to-a-screen-session-from-outside/5306#5306))

Alternately, you could just do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 1 2 3
do
    test="test"$i
    screen -dmS $test ./my_command $i
done
```

which will run a bare ./my_command $i in a new screen window.

You could also use a command line like this:

```
    screen -dmS $test  sh -c "ulimit 1234;./my_command $i; exec /bin/bash"
```

`sh -c "foobar"` will cause a new shell to be run and do the `foobar` command.  Here we have it run several shell commands.   The final `exec /bin/bash` starts another shell so you don't lose the screen if ./my_command exits.