# How to send a message in Minecraft before rebooting the server?

Tags: linux, cron

I have a Ubuntu Linux Server 14.04 LTS which is running a Minecraft server.
I want it to reboot every 6 hours. I have that now and after the reboot, it starts the Minecraft server.

Now what I want. I have the server console in a screen session named cds_screen. Is there a way to do something like `screen -d -r cds_screen && say Server is restarting && sudo reboot`?
The server runs as jebg user and not as root so can anyone help me?

Comment: Just curious: Why do you want to reboot the machine every 6 hours?

Comment: Because else thats better for the machine. I don't want it to always run.

Comment: Is your system so unstable it will crash unless occasionally rebooted? (If so, that's the root of your problems.) I can't think of another reason you'd want to cause downtime.

Comment: What is "better for the machine" exactly? Looks like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: i mean it is better for the computer if it doesn't run always.

Answer (score 3):

1. If you have to reboot your server *every 6 hours*, you are *probably* doing something wrong.
   If you're doing this because of memory leaks in Minecraft or something like that, you might want to consider only restarting Minecraft, not the whole system.
2. You can [send keystrokes to a `screen` session "from the outside"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5305/sending-input-to-a-screen-session-from-outside). <sub>(Searching really does wonders sometimes…)</sub>
   If the `screen` session is running as a different user than the current one, you will have to preface that command with `su <user> -c` and enclose it with quotes.

---

Edit: There's even [a Minecraft-related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13953/28235) here on U&L Stack Exchange that does almost exactly what you want.

Comment: can i do the su user -c in the /etc/crontab file?

Comment: @BSteurful When you're using `/etc/crontab`, you could just specify the correct user instead of using `su`. The Minecraft user wouldn't be able to initiate the reboot, though, so you would need two crontab entries. This in turn will allow you to send the "restart warning" a few minutes before the actual reboot (which is far less frustrating for your users).

Comment: Yes I understand. I try to say it 5 minutes before but that doesnot work also

Comment: @BSteurful Can you be more specific on how it doesn't work?

Comment: Well, it totally does not do anything. I have:
5 * * * * jebg screen -d -r cds_screen && say TEST
and that does not work

Comment: well, he does something. He laggs for a second but he does not send the command

Comment: @BSteurful Two things: Are you aware that that cronjob will only run *at 5 minutes past the hour*, not *every 5 minutes*? And the way you're currently running it, `say` is interpreted as a shell command, instead of being sent to the Minecraft server. If you had read the [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5305/sending-input-to-a-screen-session-from-outside) I gave in my answer, you should have figured out that you will need something like `screen -S cds_screen -X stuff "say TEST$(printf \\r)"`…

Comment: I figured that out now but it still wont work.

Comment: @BSteurful What does your `crontab` line look like now?

Comment: jebg screen -S cds_console -X stuff 'say TEST'

Comment: @BSteurful You either haven't copied the whole line or you have created an invalid line (it's lacking the time/date specifiers). Also, you left out the `$(printf \\r)`, so your crontob "types" the command into the Minecraft server's prompt, but doesn't "press Enter" to execute it. Note that you will need double quotes (") instead of single quotes (') for the `printf` to work.

Comment: okey so no i have this:
28 17 * * * jebg screen -S cds_console -X stuff "say TEST$(printf \\r)" But it still wont work

Comment: okey it works now but he does not press auto enter he adds say TESTr

Comment: Does anyone know how to fix becuase it became very anoying

Comment: okey i looked it up and I replaced $(printf \\r) with ^M and now it finally does work